# Mysql criteria in where clause not reporting properly

Tags: mysql, where-clause, in-clause

I have the following Mysql query which is working perfectly well apart from the Sum part. The result I am getting is that the Sum_IO and Sum_NIO is being calculated over the whole table as if the criteria part

`Cast(oee_main_interim.TS As date) = CurDate()`

is being ignored. What I want is the query will only sum the values which fall under today's date (curdate()):

```
Select
  oee_main_interim.NAME As Machine_ID,
  oee_machinenames.Name As Name,
  voee_mach_shifts.curr_Shift As curr_Shift,
  Sum((oee_main_interim.Left_IO + oee_main_interim.Right_IO)) As Sum_IO,
  Sum((oee_main_interim.Left_NIO + oee_main_interim.Right_NIO)) As Sum_NIO
From
  (oee_main_interim Join
  voee_mach_shifts On voee_mach_shifts.ID = oee_main_interim.NAME) Join
  oee_machinenames On oee_machinenames.ID = oee_main_interim.NAME
Where
  Cast(oee_main_interim.TS As date) = CurDate() And
  oee_main_interim.Shift In (Select
    voee_mach_shifts.curr_Shift
  From
    voee_mach_shifts Join
    oee_machinenames On oee_machinenames.ID = voee_mach_shifts.ID
  Group By
    voee_mach_shifts.curr_Shift, oee_machinenames.ID
  Order By
    oee_machinenames.ID)
Group By
  oee_main_interim.NAME, oee_machinenames.Name, voee_mach_shifts.curr_Shift
Order By
  oee_system.oee_main_interim.NAME
```

Comment: What's the type of `oee_main_interim.TS`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DATE(yourfield)=CURDATE()` to match only the date part of the timestamp or datetime field.

Comment: i tried that originally but phpmyadmin changed it to include `cast`